# Problem with dumpbin.exe using vcpkg for compile caffe2 win10

Tags: c++, caffe2, vcpkg, dumpbin

When try to use `vcpkg` with `vs2015` to install `caffe2:x64-windows` in windows 10 I obtain an error with `dumpbin.exe`:

> Dump of file E:\vcpkg\packages\caffe2_x64-windows\debug\lib\Caffe2_CPU.lib
>       LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'E:\vcpkg\packages\caffe2_x64-windows\debug\lib\Caffe2_CPU.lib'

I think that the problem is about the version of `dumpbin.exe` used in the process, it can't open big lib files, this one is bigger than 2 GB, but in the directory `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin` I found directories like amd64_x86 with other version of `dumpbin` but I dont know how to configure `vcpkg` to use this version of `dumpbin` program.

**Resolved**

I resolve my problem checking the code in the solution of vcpkg, I changed all the paths of the type "VC" / "bin" for "VC" / "amd64_x86", in this way I use the chaintool used by vcpkg, after compiling caffe2 I undo my changes.

Comment: "cannot open file" is not a version problem.  It is a FileNotFound problem, the 3rd boolean literal.  Type "dumpbin asdf" to see it.

Comment: It is not a problem location, If I use dumpbin from amd64_x86 and the command didn't output any error, I thing the dumpbin.exe can open big lib files, this one is bigger than 2 GB.

Comment: Yes, 2GB is a hard limit on MapViewOfFile().  Get practical advice by explaining why you need such a giant dump.